# bash: special character detection ( & ` ´ ' " ~ / | \ [ ] $ * ; ) via if;then

Tags: bash, character, detection

Wrecking my head over this for days, i've tried quite a few solutions to this. Each method worked to some degree (searched here on stackoverflow), but each method failed to pick up most of the special characters. 
(and i'm really not good with the ` '  " [ { characters for if checks)

Basically i want to detect if one of these characters is in the filename  ( & ` ´  ' " ~ / | \ [ ] $ * ; ) if the user selects a file and i'll make an error dialogue and a exit 0 in the code.

I'm currently using this:

```
STARTUPFILE="$(/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to activate" -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set thefile to choose file with prompt \"choose file \"" -e "do shell script (\"echo \"&(quoted form of POSIX path of thefile as Unicode text)&\"\")")"


FILENAME=$(basename "$STARTUPFILE") # via osascript input dialogue

if [[ $FILENAME = *[( & ` ´  ' " ~ / | \ [ ] $ * ; )]* ]]; then
```

What's the best way to detect all of them short of only allowing a-Z & 0-9?

Comment: Do you consider space a special character, too?

Comment: Also try `echo {a..Z}`, returns ``a ` _ ^ ]  [ Z`` for me.

Comment: Why those characters in particular? No existing file will contain `/`, since that is not a valid character (ignoring the fact that OS X will silently change it to `:` but still display it as `/` in the Finder), and there are many other valid but equally strange characters that you aren't checking for.

Comment: @ chepner: jut about every character can be used in a filename in OSX that i listed, every character is one that i want to avoid. Just : isn't allowed in the Finder, while the file system does it's own stuff with : as you said. I just want to filter out all of them since some of the files that the input dialogue from osascript returns have  & ` ´  ' " / \ in their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but nothing except limiting it to a-Z and 0-9 worked so far, but then i'd have to go the other way around and allow specific characters.

I'll post the answer here if anyone wants it.

I've experimented around with a few things in the morning (heh, i can never solve problems like these coding at night) and got something working.

It's this:

```
if [[ $FILENAME = *['&''#''$''['']''\/''\'':''|'';''{''}''´''`''"''*''~'"'"]* ]]; then
```

I had to escape just about every character with ', except escaping ' with a double " " at the end. Also as chepner mentioned, / converts to : in OSX, so checking for it is done via / and :, hence both in the code.

Only this method worked so far.

written a little shell for checking some filenames:

```
if [[ $FILENAME = *['&''#''$''['']''\/''\'':''|'';''{''}''´''`''"''*''~'"'"]* ]]
then
    echo FILENAME = "$FILENAME"  >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
    echo FILENAME does not pass character filter >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
    echo " " >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
else
    echo FILENAME = "$FILENAME"  >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
    echo FILENAME passes character filter >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
    echo " " >> "/Users/zero/Desktop/text.txt"
fi
```

that gives the following log output:

```
FILENAME = _PI   something normal even with () quotes or - + _ .iso
FILENAME passes character filter

FILENAME = _PI  _ something.iso
FILENAME passes character filter

FILENAME = _PI  - something.iso
FILENAME passes character filter

FILENAME = _PI  ! something.iso
FILENAME passes character filter

FILENAME = _PI  ? something.iso
FILENAME passes character filter

 FILENAME = _PI  + something.iso
FILENAME passes character filter

FILENAME = _PI  # something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI ' something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI " something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI [ something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI ] something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI { something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI } something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI * something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI : something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI \ something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI & something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI ` something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI ´ something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI | something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI ~ something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter

FILENAME = _PI $ something.iso
FILENAME does not pass character filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if echo "$FILENAME" | grep -qe '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close; you just need to escape certain characters that the shell will treat specially. The spaces must be omitted, unless you intend to match the space character as well.

```
if [[ $FILENAME = *[\(\&\`´\'\"~/\|\\[]\$*\;\)]* ]]; then
```

It can be simpler to store the pattern in a variable:

```
pattern=$'*[(&`´\'"~/|\\[]$*;)]*'
if [[ $FILENAME = $pattern ]]; then
```

If you are just trying to escape pattern and regex metacharacters, you might be able to just use the `%q` format with `printf`.

```
$ some_regex='(foo|bar)*[a&]'
$ printf '%q\n' "$some_regex"
\(foo\|bar\)\*\[a\&\]
```

Comment: I know this should work, but it does not work at all, neither the pattern method or the check in the if directly. I guess some weirdness from the Finder and osascript is contributing to that, or if it's just yosemite messing with me. I'll try to experiment a bit more.